# How to setup a reusable Geb test script (to be used by other test scripts)

Tags: spock, geb

So I have just created a geb script that tests the creation of a report. Let's call this `Script A`

I have other test cases I need to run that are dependent on the previous report being created, but I still want the `Script A` to be a stand alone test. we will call the subsiquent script `Script B`

Furthermore `Script A` generates a pair of numbers that will be needed in subsequent scripts (to verify data got recorded accurately)

Is there a way I can setup geb such that `Script B` executes 'Script A`and is able to pull those 2 numbers from`Script A`to be used in`Script B`?

In summary there will be a number a scripts that are dependent on the actions of `Script A` (which is itself a test) I want to be able to modularize `Script A` so that it can be executed from other scripts. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: I wanted to add that I want to avoid repeating myself. I know that a given GEB spec is designed to be able to be independently of anything else. But since this report creation process is required for any subsequent specs, I would have to essnetially copy and paste `Script A` into the setupSpec for all the subsequent scripts, and that's what I want to avoid. but since `Script A` is a test it shouldn't be a part of the page objects. And this is the dilemma I have in regards to to Specs being independent of one another. I feel that there are cases (like this one) specs should be executed in order

Comment: What do you mean by `script`? is it a groovy script file or a `class`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reuse and not repeating yourself I would put the report creation into a separate method call in a new class such as ReportGenerator, this would generate the report given a set of parameters (if required) and return the report figures for use in whatever test you like.

You could then call that in any spec you want, with no reliance on other specs.

Comment: yeah that's what I ended up doing. I technically had to repeat myself once though, since I have the spec, and now I have a method that does the same thing as the spec. so if something changes I will have to update both spots, but its ok